# Google maps on none google API build target Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to run Google Maps (API V1 is fine) on a none Google API build target? I have a special emulator that does not have the google api built in.

When I try adding the maps.jar to the libs folder in my project so the MapActivity can reference that I am getting the stack trace shown below.  I am using the Google Maps API V1 Maps.jar for this.

I have tried setting the manifest to use  , and also removed it, both do not work.

Thanks!

```
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       instantiate activity          ComponentInfo{com.google.android.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapMainActivity}:    java.lang.RuntimeException: stub
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at com.google.android.maps.MapMainActivity.  <init>(MapMainActivity.java:10)
 04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-04 17:23:20.553: E/AndroidRuntime(12458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  The Google API's are required.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Google Maps Android API v2. API v1 is deprecated and you won't have it working for new applications.

It is even worse with API v2. Not officially supported to run on any emulator.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've done some messing around with V2 and it does not run on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a webView and load your map from a web server.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that is too slow for our purposes.